# Multivariate normal distribution. To find the distribution of the random vector.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3) \sim N_3 (\mu, A)$, where $\mu = (0,0,0)$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 0\\1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Need to find the distribution of the random vector $(\eta_1 - \eta_2, \eta_2 + \eta_3)$.

I just started to learn the theory of probability and therefore not very well know how to solve such problems.
What algorithm to solve this problem? I have the following idea but I'm not sure:

1)Find pdf $p_{\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3} (x_1, x_2, x_3) = \frac{1}{{2 \pi}^{3/2} \sqrt{|A|}} e^{-(A^{-1}x^T, x) / 2}$, where $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

2)$\mathbb{P}(\eta_1 - \eta_2 < y_1, \eta_2 + \eta_3 < y_2) = \iiint\limits_D p_{\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3} (x_1, x_2, x_3) {d}x_1 {d}x_2 {d}x_3$, where $D = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb R^3 : x_1 - x_2 < y_1, x_2 + x_3 < y_2\}$.

This is the right way? Or you can solve it easier?

Answer (score 2):

The vector $(\eta_1 - \eta_2, \eta_2 + \eta_3)$ is normal, as a linear transform of the normal vector $(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3)$, hence one needs only its mean vector and its variance-covariance matrix to fully determine its distribution. Can you compute these?

Comment: But this is a two-dimensional vector. You claim that it is a linear combination of three-dimensional vectors. What did you mean?

Comment: I meant and wrote that this is a two-dimensional vector which is a linear combination of a three-dimensional vector... Here is a picture: $$\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1 - \eta_2\\ \eta_2 + \eta_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\eta_1\\ \eta_2\\ \eta_3\end{pmatrix}.$$ Can you find $(a,b,c,d,e,f)$?

Comment: Yes. It will be $F = \begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\ d&e&f\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$. If I understand correctly, the distribution of the vector $(\eta_1-\eta_2, \eta_2 + \eta_3)$ has the form $N_2 \big ( (0,0), G\big)$, where $G = F A F^T$. (This fact follows from theorem $\mathbb{D}[\xi] = C \mathbb{D}[\nu] C^T$, if $\xi = C \nu + \lambda$)Is it true?

Comment: Yes. And note that FAF^T is one of the two only orders in which a product of A, F and F^T even makes sense and the only one if one wants some 2x2 matrix in the end.